# GraphView Android, How to change thickness of original x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I am using the [GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/tap-listener-on-data/) library for drawing graphs in an Android app and I am very pleased with the library so far. I am using it in a fixed frame realtime scenario and have noticed that the x-axis and y-axis grid lines are thicker thatn the other unit grid lines. Is there any way I can make them similar to the other lines?

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.graph);

// Set manual X bounds
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(40);

// Set manual Y bounds
graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinY(-40);
graph.getViewport().setMaxY(60);

// Draw a border between between labels and viewport
graph.getViewport().setDrawBorder(false);

graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(11);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(6);
```

Basically I would like to change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `setHighlightZeroLines` method for the GridLabelRenderer class that is `true` by default. Code something like:

`graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setHighlightZeroLines(false);`

should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please find Line Graph Series in detail:

[Line Graph Series in detail](http://www.android-graphview.org/line-graph/)

// styling series

```
series.setTitle("Random Curve 1");
series.setColor(Color.GREEN);
series.setDrawDataPoints(true);
series.setDataPointsRadius(10);
series.setThickness(8);
```

// custom paint to make a dotted line

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{8, 5}, 0));
series2.setCustomPaint(paint);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but what you mentioned is used for modifying the data series (graph traces) not the grid-lines that I am looking for. I edited the images for clarification.